# Fuseki NullpointerException on counter increment

Tags: nullpointerexception, sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm always getting a `NullpointerException` when I launch a SPARQL query with Fuseki. The exception is related to a stats counter, but there doesn't seem to be a way to disable the stats. Please check out my [fuseki config file](https://gist.github.com/TimmyStorms/bc2014756dcec8b6b814). I launch a POST request via http://localhost/ds/query. The query result is retrieved but the exception is always there, no matter what kind of query I launch. Any idea on how I can prevent this exception?

Jena: 2.12.1, 
Fuseki: 1.1.1

```
10:39:17.333 [qtp541304857-19] WARN  org.apache.jena.fuseki.Server - Exception on counter inc
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_ServletBase.incCounter(SPARQL_ServletBase.java:190) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_ServletBase.executeLifecycle(SPARQL_ServletBase.java:173) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.serviceDispatch(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:302) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.executeAction(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:210) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_ServletBase.execCommonWorker(SPARQL_ServletBase.java:140) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_ServletBase.doCommon(SPARQL_ServletBase.java:69) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.doPost(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:324) [jena-fuseki-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
```

Comment: What else is the log file around that point?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-201

Looks like it is protected against in the 1.1.2 development version.

Comment: Any idea when fuseki2 gets final? Meanwhile, I'm going to try the current snapshot.

Comment: Verified that it works with Jena 2.13.0-SNAPSHOT and Fuseki 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  We, the project community, are finalizing the next releases at the moment so "soon".